# Restart entire server by using batch in Execute Process task in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, batch-file, ssis

I have two scheduled SSIS jobs in sql server agent on our production server. One for rebooting production server itself (lets name it 'A'), and the other one for rebooting another server (lets name it 'B')

I am simply using Execute Process Task in SSIS which will execute certain batch file. And following is the batch command:

> **shutdown /r /m \\A /t 300**
>    note: 'A' is the full name of the production server, and for another server, batch command is same only 'B'would replace 'A' in that command.

The job that to reboot Server 'B'(not production server 'A') could be executed without any issue at scheduled run time, however, for rebooting ITSELF (production server 'A'), job always fails. And here is the error message (I could hardly find any related to this issue)

> **The Process exit code was "5" while the expected was "0"**

I tried to remote to 'B' server and run the package on local 'B', still good. Also, I tried to run that batch file without either SSIS or SQL Server Agent, it was still good. So far the only thing I did not try yet is to run SSIS package locally to reboot 'A' because 'A' is not allowed to be offline during work days. (But I am guessing running SSIS package locally on 'A' server would not give me any problem)

I think it is kind of sql server agent on 'A' that block rebooting the server that is currently running on?

Any ideas or suggestions, guys? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you provide some information on why you are trying to reboot SQL Server, via SSIS?  Background might help our understanding.  This could also be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: i think the only reason that I create a SSIS package to reboot server is that I could schedule it as a job that I dont need to manually reboot on every Sat.night. or is there any method in windows could do this instead of running in sql server agent?

Comment: Actually I am not ONLY trying to reboot sql server, but the production server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is almost certainly a bad idea to have a scheduled (weekly or otherwise) reboot of SQL Server (including the server it is running on). If there is not an *extremely* good reason for doing this, it should be stopped.
2. Using SSIS for nothing other than running OS-level commands / CMD scripts / etc is grossly over-engineered. Better options are:

   1. Windows Scheduled Tasks
   2. Use a SQL Server Agent job with an **Operating system (CmdExec)** job step.
   3. Use a SQL Server Agent job with a **Transact-SQL script (T-SQL)** job step that execute `xp_cmdshell`.

Comment: thank you so much, searching for some stuff for all suggested ideas one by one now, appreciate it :)

Comment: the reason that I was asked to reboot the server is: 1. kill all the sql process, for some reason someday, one of sql job was blocked by another 'ghost' one, which cannot be killed by 'kill #' in SSMS, stuck forever;  2.Reboot sometimes help increase server performance, spare more system resources.

Comment: @LONG **1)** Did that situation happen once or twice, or repeatedly? There is no such thing as a "ghost" job. Well, there is the ghost cleanup process that removes deleted rows, but I _highly_ doubt that it is the issue here. If something is happening repeatedly, then the source can be found and fixed. **2)** This is rarely ever true, especially these days. Are you running more than just SQL Server on this server? What version of SQL Server? Are you using `sp_OA*` procs? **Either way:** rebooting the server weekly is a _very_ bad practice and should not be done.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Let me detail it little bit. Our servers are in high availability group, one day the job on primary server (still name it 'A') got interrupted because server failover to another one ('B'). After server A was back, I checked error log, the message shows me:  **Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back in database SSISDB for an AlwaysOn Availability Groups state change. Estimated rollback completion: 0%"** And the rollback process is stuck at 0% for couple hrs. Then I checked the sysprocess view ..

Comment: ..Which shows that rollback spid was blocked by another spid, i think thats why the rollback could not proceed, after that I located that process which block the rollback process, I dont have any idea what that is since the program_name did not provide me with any helpful information but **'.Net SqlClient Data Provider'** before I notice I could name a process. What happened next was what you may know already, **kill spid** pending forever, and was asked to reboot server, force to kill all the process..

Comment: The kpid for that sql process is a negative number, which cannot be tracked on production server, either, thats why I named it 'ghost' (sorry for misexplanation for this) That only happened once so far, but remains a mystery to me...

Comment: @LONG Well, then you need to look at more than just `program_name`. There are many other fields in `sys.dm_exec_sessions`, `sys.dm_exec_requests`, and `sys.dm_exec_connections`. Though **.Net SqlClient** points to app code. It could be that the Kill didn't work because it was a large transaction that was rolling back. Not everything registers its progress in order to get a completion %. Again, if this just happened once, then that's a bad reason to set up a dangerous policy such as scheduled reboots.

Comment: Thanks again @srutzky, I will take a deep look at sys views, maybe it is because of the large transaction was being rolled back. (but 0% for about 12 hrs :( ), thanks for the advices and I will discuss with my supervisor, thank you, really appreciate it ;)